# "errmsg" : "Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$graphLookup'" on mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have MongoDB shell version: 3.2.8. 
But the problem is still occurs when I try to execute the example of the document; https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/

What can be the problem?

On the document it says; `Changed in version 3.4.`

Should I upgrade the version to 3.4.

But in github they say; `Upgrade to MongoDB v3.2+`
source; `https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3682`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$graphLookup` and `$lookup` are 2 different things.

- **$lookup** was introduced in MongoDB 3.2 and should work with your
  current configuration
- **$graphLokkup** was introduced in MongoDB 3.4, so to use it you'll need 
  to upgrade to MongoDB 3.4 and enable 3.4 features.

  like this (from shell):

  `db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "3.4" } )`